Large tick-size assets queue position effects
When I look into the literature, I can see that queue position is one of the most important things in large tick-size assets. It helps to have an earlier execution and can help with the adverse selection.
I wonder when someone joins in front of the best bid queue and the order is executed quickly, how it can affect the selling that asset? The ask queue is probably very large so it will join to the back of the best ask queue making its execution probability very low. Then, how is it possible to buy and sell for one tick profit?
Thanks in advance.

Moallemi, Ciamac C. and Yuan, Kai, A Model for Queue Position Valuation in a Limit Order Book (December 1, 2016). Columbia Business School Research Paper No. 17-70, Available at SSRN: https://ssrn.com/abstract=2996221 or http://dx.doi.org/10.2139/ssrn.2996221
